# Why does this solidity function run into gas errors?

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to figure out some strange behavior. The function below takes in an array like [1,2,3,4,5], loops through it, and looks at another contract to verify ownership. I wrote it like this (taking in a controlled / limited array) to limit the amount of looping required (to avoid gas issues).  The weird part (well, to me) is that I can run this a few times and it works great, mapping the unmapped values.  It will always process as expected until I run about 50 items through it. After that, the next time it will gas out even if the array includes only one value. So, I'm wondering what's going on here...

```
    function claimFreeNFTs (uint[] memory _IDlist) external payable noReentrant {

        IERC721 OGcontract = IERC721(ERC721_contract);
        uint numClaims = 0; 

        for (uint i = 0; i < _IDlist.length; i++) {

            uint thisID = _IDlist[i];

            require(OGcontract.ownerOf(thisID)==msg.sender, 'Must own token.' );

            if ( !claimedIDList(thisID) ) {   // checks mapping here...

                claimIDset(thisID);  // maps unmapped values here;
                numClaims++;

            }

        }

        if ( numClaims > 0 ) {

            _safeMint(msg.sender, numClaims);
            emit Mint(msg.sender, totalSupply()); 
  
        } 

    }
```

Any thoughts / directions appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there was a bit more to the function, actually. I'd edited out some of what I thought was extraneous, but it turned out my error was in the extra stuff. The above does actually work. (Sorry.)  After doing the mint, I was also reducing the supply of a reserve wallet on the contract -- one that held (suprise!) 50 NFTs. So, after this function processed 50, it was making that wallet hold negative NFTs, which screwed things up.  Long story, but on Remix, I'd forgotten to set values in the constructor in the proper order, which is how I screwed it up in the first place.  Anyway, solved.